# Rails RESTful URL's: All Posts under certain Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, restful-url, friendly-url

Currently I use my posts#index action to show all posts or filter'em by category in case its specified:

**PostsController:**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
  @posts = @posts.by_category(params[:category_id]) #Custom named_scope
end
```

**Routes:**

```
map.connect '/post/by_category/:category_id', :controller => :posts, :action => :index
map.resources :users
```

So **/posts** will return *all the posts*, and **/posts/by_category/1** will return *all posts under category 1*

I wonder if there is a way of doing it more **RESTful**, and maybe to get some pretty url_paths.

I've read the guides (*Using latest 2.3 Rails branch*) but neither nested routes nor collections seemed appropiate for this case. Thanks :)

Comment: do you really need the "by_category" url? and is this rails 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
resources :posts
resources :categories do |categories|
  categories.resources :posts
end
```

Your urls then:

`/posts` - all posts

`/posts/:id` -certain post

`/categories` - all categories

`/categories/:id` - certain category

`/categories/:id/posts` - all posts within a certain category.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused, it had to be that 'reverse' way the natural one ;)