# Rails route for through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs

I am fairly new to Rails and I am creating a blog site and I need a post to have a category(s) and the end result url will be something like this - foo.com/category(title)/post(title) so after alot of Googling and then watching this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many. I have the following models but have no idea what the routes should be.

Should I now be using the index view of category to display all posts?

Model - Categorisations

```
class Categorisations < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :product_id
end
```

Model - Category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :image
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorisations
end
```

Model - Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :body, :is_verified, :publish_date, :title, :url, :tag_list, :image, :category_id
  has_many :categorisations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorisations
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts
end
```

Will give you the resources for /category/1/post/1

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Have a look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) for titles in the ulr

EDIT:

To answer your previous comment i would suggest you this: 
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@posts = @category.posts

Comment: Great, what would I need to put in my category index controller to display all posts from that category? I thought this but it's not correct @posts = categories.posts

Comment: No :( I found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827939/rails-restful-urls-all-posts-under-certain-category) which is what I want but I am completely lost with creating the controllers and views as the normal rails way would be through filtering and so the URL would show something like foo.com/?category=2 but this is not nice for a users or google. Can you point me in any direction or any resources you recommend?

Comment: Updated my answer with controller code that should work, also did you look at the railscast i linked in my answer?